# How to simplify a fraction that has matrix

Tags: matrices, divisibility, matrix-calculus

Recently, I was studying about optimum beamforming in array signal processing.  In it, the maximum output **SINR** is $$SINR=\frac{W^{H}R_sW}{W^{H}R_{i+n}W}$$ $$and\quad W=R_{i+n}^{-1}a \quad R_s=\alpha^2aa^H$$where $W \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times 1} \ R_s, R_{i+n} \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N} \ a\in \mathbb{C}^{N \times 1}$ and $R_{i+n} \ $ is invertible, $\alpha$ is a scalar, $H$ denotes the transpose conjugate.

Then, it can be simplified as $$SINR=\alpha^2a^{H}R_{i+n}^{-1}a$$

I can't figure out how this fraction is simplified. Especially the realtion between inversion and divison of the matrix.

Comment: Why are some vectors uppercase and others lowercase?

Comment: Just type like that. Should I  change the uppercase to lowercase?

Comment: Consistent notation helps. So do references. Do not assume books do not contain errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authors aren't *simplifying*, they're solving a [Rayleigh Quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient) problem.

The extremal values of the Rayleigh Quotient
$$\eqalign{
\rho = \frac{w^HAw}{w^HBw} \\
}$$
occurs at the eigenvalues of the matrix $R=B^{-1}A$

Applying this result to the current problem
$$\eqalign{
A &= \alpha^2 aa^H \\
B &= R_{i+n} \\
R &= \alpha^2B^{-1}aa^H = \alpha^2wa^H \\
}$$
results in an eigenvalue equation which is easily solved
$$\eqalign{
Rw &= \rho w\\
\alpha^2wa^Hw &= \rho w \quad\implies\quad\rho = \alpha^2a^Hw \\
}$$
Since $\operatorname{rank}(A)=1$, this is the only non-zero eigenvalue and is therefore the maximum.

Comment: really thanks! I will do some researches on Rayleigh Quotient.